# why setting num_worker=0 for DataLoader causes overwhelming CPU usage?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch-dataloader

I have a sample pytorch script to test GPU performance using resnet101

```py
import os
import csv
import torch
import time
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

from gpu_perf_utils import get_gpu_mem_info, calculate_statistics


def build_model(args):
    # Create the model
    # For ResNet & ViT models
    from torchvision.models import resnet50, resnet101, vit_b_16
    from torchvision.models import (
        ResNet50_Weights,
        ResNet101_Weights,
        ViT_B_16_Weights,
    )

    input_shape = (3, 224, 224)
    model = resnet101(weights=ResNet101_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)
    return model, input_shape


def build_dataset(args, size):
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.Resize(size),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(
                mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
            ),
        ]
    )
    dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageNet(
        root="./data/imagenet_1k",
        split="val",
        transform=transform,
    )
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset,
        batch_size=args.batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=0,
    )
    return dataset, dataloader


def main(args):

    # build model
    model, input_shape = build_model(args)

    # Set the model to train or eval mode
    if args.mode == "train":
        # Define the learning rate and weight decay
        learning_rate = 0.001
        weight_decay = 0.0001
        loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(
            model.parameters(),
            lr=learning_rate,
            momentum=0.9,
            weight_decay=weight_decay,
        )
        model.train()
    elif args.mode =

= "eval":
        model.eval()

    # Create a dummy input batch
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    fake_inputs = torch.randn(batch_size, *input_shape)
    fake_labels = (
        torch.randint(0, 1000, [batch_size])
    )

    # Use the CUDA device if available
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    model.to(device)
    fake_inputs = fake_inputs.to(device)
    fake_labels = fake_labels.to(device)
    # run one time to initialise memory
    _ = model(fake_inputs)

    # Measure the time taken to process n iters
    iters = max(min(10240 // batch_size, 1024), 128)
    throughputs = list()
    run_times = list()

    # Use bool var instead of char precision
    fp32 = True if args.precision == "fp32" else False
    fp16 = True if args.precision == "fp16" else False
    mixed = True if args.precision == "mixed" else False
    dtype = torch.float32 if fp32 else torch.float16
    scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler(enabled=mixed)

    dataset, dataloader = build_dataset(args, input_shape[1:3])
    iters = min(len(dataloader), 1024)
    if args.mode == "eval":
        with torch.no_grad():
            start_time = time.time()
            count = 0
            for inputs, _ in tqdm(dataloader):

                with torch.autocast(device_type="cuda", dtype=dtype):
                    inputs = inputs.to(device)
                    outputs = model(inputs)

                torch.cuda.synchronize()

                end_time = time.time()
                run_time = end_time - start_time
                run_times.append(run_time)
                throughput = batch_size / run_time
                throughputs.append(throughput)

                count += 1
                if count >= iters:
                    break

                start_time = time.time()

    if args.mode == "train":
        start_time = time.time()
        count = 0
        for inputs, labels in tqdm(dataloader):

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            with torch.autocast(device_type="cuda", dtype=dtype, enabled=mixed):
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                outputs = model(inputs)
                loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
            scaler.scale(loss).backward()
            scaler.unscale_(optimizer)
            if mixed:
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=0.1)
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()

            torch.cuda.synchronize()

            end_time = time.time()
            run_time = end_time - start_time
            run_times.append(run_time)
            throughput = batch_size / run_time
            throughputs.append(throughput)

            count += 1
            if count >= iters:
                break

            start_time = time.time()

    # Calculate the average throughput and memory usage
    throughput_statistics = calculate_statistics(np.array(throughputs))
    run_time_statistics = calculate_statistics(np.array(run_times))
    print(f"{throughput_statistics = }")

    print(f"Average Throughput: {throughput_statistics['mean']:.2f} images/sec")

def parse_arg():
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Train or evaluate a model")

    # Define the command line arguments
    parser.add_argument(
        "--mode",
        type=str,
        default="train",
        choices=["train", "eval"],
        help="train or eval mode",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--batch-size", type=int, default=32, help="batch size for training"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output", type=str, default="gpu_perf_info.csv", help="output csv file path"
    )

    # Create a mutually exclusive group for the precision options
    precision = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

    # Add the different arguments to the precision group
    precision.add_argument(
        "--fp32",
        action="store_const",
        dest="precision",
        const="fp32",
        help="Run with single precision float",
    )
    precision.add_argument(
        "--fp16",
        action="store_const",
        dest="precision",
        const="fp16",
        help="Run with half precision float",
    )
    precision.add_argument(
        "--mixed",
        action="store_const",
        dest="precision",
        const="mixed",
        help="Run with mixed precision float",
    )
    parser.set_defaults(precision="fp32")

    # Parse the arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Access the arguments
    mode = args.mode
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    precision = args.precision

    # Print the arguments for confirmation
    print("Mode:", mode)
    print("Batch Size:", batch_size)
    print("Precision:", precision)

    return args


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_arg()
    main(args)
```

Initially, I set `num_worker` to be 0 for the dataloader, but when I run the test, I found the script uses a lot of cpus (nearly to the number of vcpus I have) and GPU is mostly idle without any workload.

If I modified `num_worker` to some small values like 3, the cpu usage is much lower and GPU util increases a lot.

So my questions are:

1. why `num_worker = 0` consumes so much cpus? as it is claimed in the doc, setting this to 0, only main process will load the data, so what does another processes do?
2. Is is valid to change num_worker? and what value should it be set?